# How do I get the ID of a Firestore document?

Tags: go, google-cloud-firestore

I'm iterating over my user documents in Firestore, but I'm not able to see the ID of the document I'm currently reading.

```
  package main

  import (
    "context"
    firebase "firebase.google.com/go"
    "fmt"
    "google.golang.org/api/iterator"
    "google.golang.org/api/option"
    "log"
  )

   ctx := context.Background()
   sa := option.WithCredentialsFile("cert.json")
   app, err := firebase.NewApp(ctx, nil, sa)
   client, err := app.Firestore(ctx)

   iter := client.Collection("users").Documents(ctx)
   for {
     doc, err := iter.Next()
     if err == iterator.Done {
       break
     }
     if err != nil {
       fmt.Println("Error:", err)
     }

    userDoc := doc.Data()
    var customer_id string
    fmt.Println("user object ID: ", userDoc["mobile_number"])
    // ^ Works

    fmt.Println("user object ID: ", doc.documentID)
    // ^ This gives me this error "❯ doc.documentID undefined 
    // (type *"cloud.google.com/go/firestore".DocumentSnapshot
    // has no field or method documentID)"
```

As far as I can [read from the docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html) a DocumentSnapshot should have a `documentID` property that
returns the ID of the snapshot's document.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is client? Which library are you using to access it? You cannot access `documentID` because it is not an exported member (starts with lowercase letter); can you try using `doc.DocumentID`?

Comment: `client` added to the original post. According to this doc, documentID is with a small 'd'. https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html

Comment: I've also tried with `doc.DocumentID` ,  `doc.DocumentId` and different casing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Go documentation is on [godoc.org](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/firestore).

In your line `doc, err := iter.Next()` you get a [`*DocumentSnapshot`](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/firestore#DocumentSnapshot). It has a field called `Ref` which is a [`*DocumentRef`](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/firestore#DocumentRef). Its field `ID` is, according to the documentation:

```
// The ID of the document: the last component of the resource path.
ID  string
```

So to access the ID in your code, you probably need to use

```
doc.Ref.ID
```

Comment: Where can I refer ``DocumentSnapshot`` on godoc?